# Django : Can we use .exclude() on .get() in django querysets

Tags: python, django, django-models

Can we use

```
 MyClass.objects.get(description='hi').exclude(status='unknown')
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your code works as expected if you do the `exclude()` before the `get()`:

```
MyClass.objects.exclude(status='unknown').get(description='hi')
```

As @Burhan Khalid points out, the call to `.get` will only succeed if the resulting query returns exactly one row.

You could also use the [`Q` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to get specify the filter directly in the `.get`:

```
MyClass.objects.get(Q(description='hi') & ~Q(status='unknown'))
```

Note that the Q object is only necessary because you use a `.exclude` (and Django's ORM does not have a not equal field lookup so you have to use `.exclude`).

If your original code had been (note that `.exclude` has been replaced with `.filter`):

```
MyClass.objects.filter(status='unknown').get(description='hi')
```

... you could simply do:

```
MyClass.objects.get(status='unknown', description='hi')
```

Answer (score 1):

You want instead:

```
MyClass.objects.filter(description='hi').exclude(status='unknown')
```

`.get()` will raise `MultipleObjectsReturned` if your query results in more than one matching set; which is likely to happen considering you are searching on something that isn't a primary key.

Using filter will give you a QuerySet, which you can later chain with other methods or simply step through to get the results.